# How can i start some file manager in Powershell under SSH?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, ssh

I have downloaded Windows PowerShell SSH Server from [Here](http://www.powershellserver.com/). So, now i can ssh from Linux to Windows, and get to PowerShell.

But if i use another way, connect from Windows to Linux via SSH, i can run something like Midnight Commander or other File Manager. How can i run some File Manager under PowerShell under SSH from Linux?

I tried to run Far Manager, but not succeeded.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you seem to want to connect from your Linux system to your Windows system using SSH and then open a file manager to browse your Windows files, right? If that is the case, this is not possible since there is not command-line file manager in Windows. You'll have to use PowerShell commands like `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: Well, there is no such file manager, because it's impossible? Or just no one has written it yet?

Comment: Coming from SSH you only have command line output correct? In that case, Chirag64 is right, there isn't much you can do except, commands such as Set-location, get-item, get-childitem, get-content, etc.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I don't believe such an interactive application is possible to be programmed in command prompt or PowerShell. So there is no way to do this even within PowerShell, let alone connect to PowerShell from a Linux system via SSH.</s>

As pointed out by Ansgar Wiechers in the comment below, there are some File managers that run locally in a command prompt or PowerShell, but not in an SSH session.

Comment: There is [FAR](http://www.farmanager.com/), and there is also a [Midnight Commander port for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcwin32/), both of which run just fine in a command prompt or a local PowerShell console, so it I wouldn't consider it impossible. However, I didn't manage to get either of them to work in an SSH session.